# regex to find uppercase words and lowercase words

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am looking for a regex that can separate string to uppercase words and lowercase words and insert them inside an object (i just need the regex and I can move forward from there).
I am trying to build SQL like queries, this is an example:

```
SEARCH FOR hello AND LOOK AFTER FOR 1 words
```

and I want to make an object from this, that will become something like this:

```
{
 SEARCHFOR: 'hello',
 ANDLOOKAFTERFOR: '1 words'
}
```

I'm terrible at regex so sorry for the question.
thanks you all!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [`([A-Z\s]+)([a-z0-9\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/I478tJ/1)?

Comment: nice solution amhed

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed this is exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
([A-Z\s]+)([a-z0-9\s]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I478tJ/1/).

You can access the uppercase words in the first group, and the lowercase words and numbers in the second group.

**Details:**

- `([A-Z\s]+)` one or more uppercase letter or whitespace character in a capturing group.
- `([a-z0-9\s]+)` one or more lowercase letter, digit, or whitespace character in a capturing group.